# Is 'Jap' still considered an ethnic slur?

Tags: offensive-language, ethnonyms

~Seventy years after 'The War', is *Jap* still considered to be an ethnic slur in the US? Is/was it also considered offensive in the UK?

Comment: In the US, yes.

Comment: Should I feel offended if someone calls me a Brit? If not, why not?

Comment: @BarrieEngland  I don't think anybody but you gets a vote.

Comment: Then if _Brit_ isn't offensive, and I don't think it is, why is _Jap_?

Comment: @BarrieEngland The same reason why _Paki_ is considered offensive in Merry England? But, I agree that the whole idea is fundamentally and hypocritically idiotic. I find it quite offensive :|

Comment: @coleopterist: I agree. As always, context, by which I mean the wider social context, is all.

Comment: As a Japanese American, I still consider the term offensive, mostly as it demonstrates that someone doesn't know the history of the term.

Comment: If "Jap" weren't enough, the term can also be rendered "JAP," i.e. "Jewish-American Princess," a stereotype of a spoiled, materialistic girl. A *jappy* crowd in a New York bar probably doesn't have as many Asian faces in it as such a crowd in Honolulu. I'd never heard of the non-Japanese meaning before I moved to the East Coast.

Comment: @Barrie England: I regularly refer to myself as a "Brit" here, and I'm quite happy to call Americans "Yanks" (I notice they rarely do the same, but I'd be surprised if many feel either term is "offensive"). But I'd never call [Yoichi Oishi](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119/yoichi-oishi) a "Jap", and I'd fall off my perch if he used that word of himself. Actually, if he *did*, I'd probably feel compelled to advise against it, rather than assume he knew the full "resonance" of the term.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's my understanding that there are those in America who would find being called a "Yank" offensive — particularly in the South.

Comment: @ghoppe: That's my understanding too. But it's a something of a hypothetical conjecture, so I habitually ignore it. I imagine those Southerners who might be offended are still smarting over the fact that those *damned Yankees* stopped them from keeping black slaves. I don't much care if I irritate such people (to be honest, I kinda like the idea of winding them up! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  In my (once) part of the country there's a difference between *Damyankee*, which denotes the Other Side in the War Between the States (there's thus considerable overlap between *Damyankee* and *Yanqui* denoting a related brand of cultural imperialism) , and *Yankee*, which denotes either inhabitants of New England or the World's Most Hated baseball team.

Comment: @ghoppe / FumbleFingers: I wouldn't go so far as to call "Yankee"/"Yank" an offensive term in the US, although Southerners *do* use it as a pejorative for Northerners, specifically New Englanders (as StonyB noted). As a Northerner living in the South, I never took offensive to being called a Yankee because it always seemed to be playful ribbing: "you don't quite fit in here and we think that's sort of funny." Certainly some diehard Southerners may take it more seriously than that - but calling those folks "Yankees" with their connotation probably wouldn't make sense to them.

Comment: @coleopterist Maybe what would end this once and for all is if people can just agree that *all* abbreviations are just abbreviations: perhaps impolite, but never offensive. There's no reason that something as benign and common as abbreviation should be such a landmine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Jap* is still considered an offensive term in the US. From personal experience, I remember an afternoon in public school where a classmate used the word "Jap" and was scolded by the teacher. The [well-cited Wikipedia entry on the term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jap) supports this:

> Today it is generally regarded as an ethnic slur among Japanese minority populations in other countries, although English-speaking countries differ in the degree to which they consider the term offensive. In the United States, Japanese Americans have come to find the term controversial or offensive, even when used as an abbreviation.

Additionally, there's evidence that the term *can* be controversial in the UK specifically. Again from the Wikipedia:

> In 2011, following the term's offhand use in a March 26 article appearing in *The Spectator* ("white-coated Jap bloke"), the Minister of the Japanese Embassy in London protested that "most Japanese people find the word ‘Jap’ offensive, irrespective of the circumstances in which it is used."

Perhaps it goes without saying, but the term is considered offensive due to its usage by Americans during WWII. (Before the war it was not considered offensive.) Once more from the Wikipedia entry on the term:

> Later popularized during World War II to describe those of Japanese descent, "Jap" was then commonly used in newspaper headlines to refer to the Japanese and Imperial Japan. "Jap" became a derogatory term during the war, more so than "Nip." Veteran and author Paul Fussell explains the usefulness of the word during the war for creating effective propaganda by saying that "Japs" "was a brisk monosyllable handy for slogans like 'Rap the Jap' or 'Let's Blast the Jap Clean Off the Map.'"

Comment: Thanks. It's bizarre that even the Japanese government considers the term offensive.

Comment: @coleopterist The Japanese government is quite schizophrenic -- opinions on various issues differ even within each party. Many Japanese politicians would probably take no offense to the term.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka After remarking on [this reaction](http://images.spectator.co.uk/wit-and-wisdom/letters/6845783/part_3/letters.thtml) by the "Minister, Embassy of Japan", the WP article actually goes on to state, "In Japan the word is not popularly known, used and referenced since Japanese are the majority of the population and there is no setting to create distinctions." Very odd.

Answer (score 8):

My parents are Japanese, I was born in Japan, and I'm a Japanese-English translator living in Canada.

Of the people I know, second and third-generation Japanese-Canadians seem to take the most offense. Part of it may be due to the lingering anger of having been cast aside (and in many cases shunned and mistreated) by the rest of Canada during World War II.

Meanwhile, even among the well-read, the Japanese living in Japan seem to have no trouble using the word "jap" both in communication amongst themselves and in communication with English-speakers. After all, the Japanese often find it stylish and convenient both to write in English and to abbreviate liberally. If someone in Japan does take offense to it, it's often only because they'd been instructed to.

So, to (kind of) answer your question, considering many of us don't care as much anymore, I think the offensive use of the term "jap" is probably on its way out, being replaced by -- or returned to -- its benign use as a natural and linguistically sound abbreviation. Personally, I welcome this, and wish it to happen sooner rather than later. In fact, I use the nickname `japinthebox` frequently online, and no one seems upset by it -- at least, not enough to say so.

"Jap" was probably already in use before the war without any racial overtones. I only find it offensive when it's said to emphasize a remark that already suggests racism, and I argue that people who see nothing wrong with the word nonetheless become upset simply because they recognize that some other people still do. It's a strange self-perpetuating sentiment.

"Jap" differs from "nip" in that the latter isn't even English, and so one must have gone out of their way to use it with vile, whereas "Jap" is an abbreviation of "Japanese" with legitimate usage outside of the war and probably even before it. We say "the Afghans" quite casually now, and it's used just as casually in the war in Afghanistan, but just because of the way the war is going there, there may come a time when people insist that we stop using the word "Afghans" and say "Afghanis" instead -- which given our current perspective, we know would be just a little bit absurd.

Comment: Interesting POV; thank you. Re: nip, my understanding is that _even today_ Japanese in Japan rarely refer to their country as anything other than _Nihon_ or _Nippon_. I suspect that _Nippon_ was a lot more prominent back in 1939 than it is today. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @coleopterist Yep, that's exactly right. "Nihon" and "Nippon" are equally correct, but younger people especially don't seem to use "Nippon" as much -- partially for phonetic reasons, but also just because it's come to be associated with old people. It also sounds more official, so it tends to be used by news anchors and corporations and such. "Nip" isn't recognized as anything other than a wartime racial slur, as it isn't even phonetically comfortable. The other one that went out of usage immediately after the war is "Dai Nippon Teikoku" (Great Empire of Japan) -- for obvious reasons.

Comment: I've never even heard of "nip" as a pejorative for Japanese people until today. I always assumed it was something you do to something in the bud.

Answer (score 7):

Interesting.
from far off Kiwi land aka New Zealand.
The following are words with country name or nationality implicit or clear.
 There are, of course, many ethnic slurs which are not country related terms.

**Offensive:**

Jap - not unknown. Never polite. Can be rude. 
Paki - rare. Would usually be rude.
Chink - increasingly rare. Always dismissive to rude.

**Uncertain to risky:**

Frenchy - more dismissive than offensive.
Iti (I-tie) (obsolescent)
Dutchie

**Casual** - perhaps a hint of good humoured denigration amongst mates:

Brit - moderately common.
Pom - slightly dismissive sometimes. Depends on context. (= Brit = Prisoner of Mother England)
Ozzie - Australian. Common. Informal. Bantering. Never rude per se.
Dali - common, fading. Dalmation - product of NZ gum-digging years).
Ruski - rarer of late

Comment: Roosky is how you pronounce "Russian" (русски) in Russian.

Answer (score 3):

I spoke with an American about this question recently.  He said, as someone with a mother from Japan, that he still found this term offensive.  At the same time, he said that he understood that many people simply don't know better.

Answer (score 1):

"Jap" isn't used only about Japanese people.

In Australia and New Zealand, kabocha is sometimes called a "Japanese pumpkin" according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabocha), or a "Jap pumpkin", according to the blog [Stomachs on legs](http://stomachsonlegs.blogspot.com.au/2007/10/more-racist-food-labelling-jap-pumpkin.html). It's sometimes sold in grocery stores as "Jap pumpkin". Based on the comments in the blog post, I'd say some people find the term acceptable, some do not.

Answer (score -3):

The"J" word is no more acceptable and as racially charged for not only Japanese Americans, or Asian Americans in general, but also for many native Japanese, as the "N" word" is for African Americans and blacks from all over the globe. And akin to the "C" word for Chinese - and many do not make the distinction. I find it appalling that there are people here casually discussing this as if the term is somehow now acceptable, a linguistic term or even trendy. The word is NEVER acceptable, both in the US and Japan. As the spouse of a Japanese man (who knows very well what it means in all of its negative and racial connotations - and detests its use) and, the parent of a bicultural/racial child, who was called the "J" word on the playground, our family knows well what this racist and foul term means. It is always interesting to me that derogatory terms against Asians are often downplayed as if Asians are still fair game. Wake up people.

Comment: People discuss all kinds of words here. You can find questions about words like *Kraut*, *Paki* and *negro* too. You might infer from the question that the asker is neither from the US nor from UK - he is clearly not exposed to the culture you have been exposed to.

Comment: What exactly are you talking about when you say "J" word and "C" word? Do you mean we shouldn't refer to Japanese people as Japanese and Chinese people as Chinese? I ask because I don't know of a "C" word that is short for Chinese.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel the racial slur for Chinese people rhymes with "pink".